# AngularJS service is not a singleton

Tags: angularjs, singleton

As far as I know, all AngularJS services are singletons.
However, in my implementation this seems not to be true.
I am using `AngularJS v1.4.14`.
I have created two controllers where one service is injected in both.

***FooController***

```
angular.module('fooModule').controller('FooController', [
  'myService',
  function (myService) {
    ...
  }
]);
```

***BarController***

```
angular.module('barModule').controller('BarController', [
  'myService',
  function (myService) {
    ...
  }
]);
```

***MyService***

```
'use strict';
angular.module('myModule').service('myService', MyService);
function MyService() {
  var initialize = function () {
    console.log("INITIALIZE");
  };

  initialize();
}
```

I get INTIALIZE twice in the log.
And after additional testing I am pretty sure, there are two `myService` instances. One per controller.
Now keep in mind that this comes from an old project, which is legacy code and there can be any configuration that I am not aware of.

**Can you explain this? How can I make my service a singleton?**

Comment: The controllers are defined in two different apps, `fooModule` and `barModule`. How are the two modules instantiated? If the page creates two injectors, the service will be instantiated twice. If the page loads another page, it will load a new injector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there was an initialization of Angular per module in my code

```
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
  angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('foo'), ['fooModule']);
});

angular.element(document).ready(function () {
  angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('bar'), ['barModule']);
});
```

I changed this to a single angular initialization for all modules

```
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['fooModule', 'barModule']);
});
```

Now, services injected in different controllers indeed behave as singletons